Express JS population returning more fields
I have a tour schema:
const toursSchema = new mongoose.Schema(
  {
    name: String,
    slug: String,
    duration: {
      type: Number,
      require: [true, "A tour must have a duration!"],
    },
    createdAt: {
      type: Date,
      default: Date.now(),
    },

    ratingsAverage: {
      type: Number,
      default: 0.0,
      min: 0.0,
      max: 5.0,
    },
    ratingsQuantity: {
      type: Number,
      default: 0,
    },
    price: {
      type: Number,
      required: [true, "A tour must have some price!"],
    },
    guides: [
      {
        type: mongoose.Schema.ObjectId,
        ref: "User",
      },
    ],
    leadGuide: {
      type: mongoose.Schema.ObjectId,
      ref: "User",
    },
    images: [String],
    startDates: [Date],
  },
  {
    timestamps: true,
    toJSON: { virtuals: true },
    toObject: { virtuals: true },
  }
);

toursSchema.virtual("durationWeeks").get(function () {
  return this.duration / 7;
});

toursSchema.virtual("reviews", {
  ref: "Review",
  foreignField: "tour",
  localField: "_id",
});

toursSchema.pre(/^find/, function (next) {
  this.populate({
    path: "guides",
    select: "-__v -passwordChangedAt -_id",
  });
  next();
});

toursSchema.pre(/^find/, function (next) {
  this.populate({
    path: "leadGuide",
    select: "-__v -passwordChangedAt -_id",
  });
  next();
});

toursSchema.pre("save", function (next) {
  this.slug = slugify(this.name, { lower: true });
  next();
});

const TourModel = mongoose.model("Tour", toursSchema);

module.exports = TourModel;

I also have a review schema:
const mongoose = require("mongoose");

const reviewSchema = new mongoose.Schema(
  {
    review: {
      type: String,
      required: [true, "A review must have a review!"],
      trim: true,
    },
    rating: {
      type: Number,
    },
    createdAt: {
      type: Date,
      default: Date.now(),
    },
    tour: {
      type: mongoose.Schema.ObjectId,
      ref: "Tour",
      required: [true, "A review must belong to a tour!"],
    },
  },
  {
    toJSON: {
      virtuals: true,
      versionKey: false,
    },
    toObject: { virtuals: true },
  }
);

reviewSchema.pre(/^find/, function (next) {
  this.populate({
    path: "user",
    select: "name photo -_id",
  });
  next();
});

reviewSchema.pre(/^find/, function (next) {
  this.populate({
    path: "tour",
    select: "name",
  });
  next();
});

const ReviewModel = mongoose.model("Review", reviewSchema);

module.exports = ReviewModel;

Now the problem is when I am fetching review the review object looks like this
"reviews": [
    {
        "_id": "661489f138a1c514bd7c328b",
        "review": "This is a very nice tour.",
        "rating": 5,
        "createdAt": "2024-04-09T00:20:58.278Z",
        "tour": {
            "_id": "66147210f4db8c1f54af0e6f",
            "name": "Royal Bengal Tiger Safari",
            "guides": [
                {
                    "name": "Selim Ahmed",
                    "email": "selimahmed@guide.com",
                    "photo": "default.jpg",
                    "role": "guide"
                }
            ],
            "leadGuide": {
                "name": "Abul Hossain",
                "email": "abularafat@lead-guide.com",
                "photo": "default.jpg",
                "role": "lead-guide"
            },
            "durationWeeks": null,
            "id": "66147210f4db8c1f54af0e6f"
        },
        "id": "661489f138a1c514bd7c328b"
    }
]

I only want to show the name and id in tour. But it is also returning "guides", "leaGuide". I don't want them to show in my response. Also I don't want to see "id" in the response.
Thanks for helping me.
I have also tried to using in reviewSchema select: "-guides, -leadGuide" but it doesn't work. Can someone explain this to me, please? I am a beginner.
